# Perl mechanize script no form defined

Tags: forms, perl, post, mechanize

I'm getting an error `No form defined at cqSubmitter.pl at line 33` which is the second `set_fields` method. Other times I get an `Error POSTing http://micron.com` `Internal Server Error at line 39` , which corresponds to the last `click_button` line.

I'm not really sure what's going on, and why it's saying no form defined? The first half of the code which includes the  first `click_button` method works fine and saves the correct page, but when I try `set_fields` for the second time, it errors out.

Anyone familiar with the Mechanize package realize what's going on here?

```
use Data::Dumper;
use HTTP::Request::Common qw(GET);
use WWW::Mechanize;


#Prepopulated information
my $types_ = "";
my $dept_ = "";
my $group_ = "";


#Create new WWW::Mechanize object
my $mech = WWW::Mechanize->new( 'ssl_opts' => { 'verify_hostname' => 0 } );
my $url = "http://f2prbrequest";

#Fetch URL or Die Tryin'
$mech ->get($url);

$fname = "user";
$pswd = "password";


#Login to ClearQuest form using credentials
$mech->set_fields(
    USER => $fname
   ,PASSWORD => $pswd
);


$mech->click_button(
   name => 'Submit'
 );


#Set fields and actually fill out ClearQuest Form
$mech->set_fields(
    types => $types_
   ,dept => $dept_
   ,group => $group_
  );


$mech->click_button(
    name => 'submit1'
 );

$mech->save_content("clearQuestFilled.html");
```

Comment: It might be worth adding a call to `save_content` just before the set_fields call -- then you can see what page the code is trying to work with. That's helped me track down a few similar issues!

Comment: Actually..It's working now. I only get that error sometimes. Could it be the webpage itself behaving weirdly?

Comment: That definitely sounds like you're getting a different page, sometimes, yeah.